# How do I use pandas to get particular values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to use pandas to read a table and then look at a column and get certain values if the column fulfills a condition.

This is what I have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(6,3),columns=list('ABC'))
df[C]>0
```

So that in this scenario, I want the code to filter C, and output both A and C if the value in C is greater than 0.

From here:

```
U          A         B         C
0  1.438161 -0.210454 -1.983704
1 -0.283780 -0.371773  0.017580
2  0.552564 -0.610548  0.257276
3  1.931332  0.649179 -1.349062
4  1.656010 -1.373263  1.333079
5  0.944862 -0.657849  1.526811
```

I want to get:

```
         A          C

 -0.283780  0.017580
  0.552564  0.257276
  1.656010  1.333079
  0.944862  1.526811
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try this condition

```df[df['C'] > 0][['A' , 'C']]```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using df.loc and setting the columns you want back:

```
from numpy.random import randn 
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(6,3),columns=list('ABC')) 
df.loc[df['C']>0, ['A', 'C']]  


       A     C
1 -2.642 0.472
3  0.328 0.519
4 -0.298 0.721
5 -0.671 1.797
```